# Starting multiple thread processes to process a queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

Using below code I start to thread processes, `write_process` writes to a queue and `read_process` reads from a queue :

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
class QueueFun():

    def writing_queue(self, work_tasks):
        while True:
            print("Writing to queue")
            work_tasks.put(1)
            time.sleep(1)

    def read_queue(self, work_tasks):
        while True:
            print('Reading from queue')
            work_tasks.get()
            time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QueueFun()
    work_tasks = Queue()

    write_process = Process(target=q.writing_queue,
                                     args=(work_tasks,))
    write_process.start()

    read_process = Process(target=q.read_queue,
                                     args=(work_tasks,))
    read_process.start()

    write_process.join()
    read_process.join()
```

Running above code prints:

```
Writing to queue
Reading from queue
Writing to queue
Reading from queue
Writing to queue
Writing to queue
Reading from queue
Writing to queue
```

How to start N processes to read from the queue?

I tried starting 3 processes using below code but just 1 process is started, this is because the .join() prevents the second process from starting?:

```
for i in range(0 , 3):
    read_process = Process(target=q.read_queue,
                                     args=(work_tasks,))
    print('Starting read_process' , i)
    read_process.start()
    read_process.join()
```

I also considered using a `Pool` as described in https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html but this seems just relevant for transforming an existing collection :

```
print pool.map(f, range(10))
```

How to start n threads where each thread processes a shared queue?

Comment: Google 'Python producer consumer queue', and try hard to not focus on 'join':(

Comment: @MartinJames thanks, those articles such as https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Producer_Consumer_using_Queue.php refer to the threading module instead of multiprocessing module  - do you suggest using threading instead of multiprocessing or combine the two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put it to list, and join it outside of creation loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QueueFun()
    work_tasks = Queue()

    write_process = Process(target=q.writing_queue,
                            args=(work_tasks,))
    write_process.start()

    processes = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        processes.append(Process(target=q.read_queue,
                                 args=(work_tasks,)))

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    write_process.join()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```